# Python sys.exit() not working in Windows 7 command prompt

Tags: python, cmd, keyboardinterrupt

So I have a python script which I run in the command prompt as you'd expect

```
python myscript.py
```

Inside my script I have a line that intercepts Ctrl+C and is suppose to tidy up a few things and shut down the script.

```
def check_for():
    while True:
        # Perform check and operation if needed

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    try:
        threading.Thread(target=check_for).start()
        # Perform script duties

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Tidying up a few things"
        # Performs tidying duties
        sys.exit()
```

But it doesn't seem to actual exit the program. It prints the message so I know its getting that interrupt signal, but I don't have control back in the command prompt and when I look in Task Manager I see the python process for it still running. I only regain control once I end that process. In fact, even if the program runs to completion normally without being interrupted the process remains.

My program does spawn child threads, which is why I use *sys.exit()* over other methods which I heard can't be excepted and do more abrupt ends.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a cross platform method of doing this (which is what I thought sys.exit() was)?

**Edit:** So I've isolated the issue. I created a small test script and it seems to be when I create a thread it just doesn't die and thus the program never exits. I've changed my initial code to show the setup.

Comment: Try adding a `print` statement *right before* `sys.exit()`, i.e. after tidying. Does that get printed?

Comment: Try, `sys.exit('Tidying up a few things')`. Additionally, when you use the Python interactive shell and run `sys.exit()` after `import sys`, does your shell exit normally?

Comment: @ace in my actual code the print statement IS right before the sys.exit() call.
And Juxhin yeah, when I run it in the shell it closes properly. Does having it in that if statement change anything?

Comment: No, if it's printing it out properly it doesn't. Have you tried my other suggesting of placing the exit message within the exit function?

Comment: Yeah. Like I said the issue seems to actually be that the thread isn't being killed for some reason. Does sys.exit() not kill threads? I think it might be because these threads have infinite while loops running...